# Fluentd: How to solve fluentd forward plugin error?

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to transfer log from one server(A) to another server(B) using fluentd.
I use forward_output plugin in A and use forward input server in B, but I got there following error.

```
2017-10-26 16:59:27 +0900 [warn]: #0 [forward_output] detached forwarding server 'boxil-log' host="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port=24224 hard_timeout=true

2017-10-26 17:00:43 +0900 [warn]: #0 [forward_output] failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=0 next_retry_seconds=2017-10-26 17:00:44 +0900 chunk="55c6e86321afbab5bed145d53e679865" error_class=Errno::ETIMEDOUT error="Connection timed out - connect(2) for \"xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\" port 24224"

2017-10-26 17:01:42 +0900 [warn]: #0 [forward_output] failed to flush the buffer. retry_time=6 next_retry_seconds=2017-10-26 17:01:42 +0900 chunk="55c6e86321afbab5bed145d53e679865" error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ForwardOutput::NoNodesAvailable error="no nodes are available"
```

This is the code for output in A.

```
<match system.*.*>
  @type forward
  @id forward_output

  <server>
    name boxil-log
    host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    port 24224
  </server>
</match>
```

This is the code for input in B.

```
<source>
  @type forward
  @id forward_input
</source>
```

I want to know the meaning of this error, the reason I got this and the way solving this.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi @hiromu by any chance you manage to get this problem cracked... I'm also facing it.

Comment: @Govind Mantri  Sorry for my super late replay. I was actually a simple mistake. I didn't open server B tcp connection of port 24224.